# Create VM from Image that Contains Data Disks within Image

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

Trying to create a vm from a custom image - that image has 1 data disk with data in it already.

When running our plan:

Error: creating Windows Virtual Machine: (Name "xxxxxxxxx" / Resource Group "xxxxxxxx"): compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidParameter" Message="StorageProfile.dataDisks.lun does not have required value(s) for image specified in storage profile." Target="storageProfile"

Do we need to specify data disks if they already exist in the image?  How do you handle that in your code?

````
 data_disks = [
      {
        disk_name  = "data1"
        lun_number = "1"
        caching    = "ReadWrite"
```


 data_disks = [
      {
        disk_name  = "data1"
        lun_number = "1"
        caching    = "ReadWrite"`
````

Comment: I don't know why that code block is in there 2x's - ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify the `data disks block` in your Terraform code when creating a VM from a custom image that already has data disks. Instead, use the `os disk` block to specify the details of the OS disk, and the VM will use the `data disks` included in the image automatically.

And there might be an issue with the `"lun"` property. Ensure that the lun specified in the storage profile matches with the data disk of the custom VM image.

Add below disk details in your code as shown:

```bash
 os_disk {
    name              = "osidsk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
```

Refer the template structure from [terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment) for a detailed idea.

I tried the below template with `Os_disk block` for a custom VM image in my environment and terraform was successfully initialized without any errors with a valid configuration.

```bash
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                  = xxxx
  location              = location
  resource_group_name   = resourcegroupname
  nic_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.example.id]
  vmsize               = "Standard_F2"

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = sku
    version   = "latest"
  }

  os_disk {
    name              = "osidsk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage" //(local VM image)
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = local.vmname
    admin_username = "user"
    admin_password = "xxxxx"
  }
}
```

***Output:***

[image]